# i am trying to run my app and i am getting this error message?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dart

I am using flutter in android studio. All my Dart files contain no errors, my images file has an avatar image named `avatar.png` but I get this error:

> No file or variants found for asset: images/avatar.png.

Is my images file not in the right folder? If yes where should I paste it in my app project files?

flutter:

```
uses-material-design: true
# To add assets to your application,
# add an assets section,
# like this: assets: -images / avatar.png# - images / a_dot_ham.jpeg
Widget logo() {
    return new Hero(
        tag: 'hero',
        child: new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            radius: 80.0,
            child: Image.asset('images/avatar.png'),
        ),
    );
}
```

> Error detected in pubspec.yaml: No file or variants found for asset:
>   images/avatar.png.
>
> Error: Failed to build asset bundle

Answer (score 1):

Please Check Your Avtar.png file in assets folder think you forgot or Remove that file..

> Block quote

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Flutter documentation for images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)?

You are to place all resources (e.g. images) in an `assets` (in your case, `images`) folder in the root directory and specify it in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Also take a look at the [Image](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html) constructor.